# How to write a list of structs into a file in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, io

I'm going to use `List` as a data structure to temporarily save real time data and I want to write it into a file.

The program receives millions of data in real time, so I want to reduce as much latency and overhead as possible. At first, I just combined data (`String`) and saved it in `String` (into a list), but I've found out that using a fixed list with structs is better because the process of combining strings is expensive(before writing a file, when temporarily saving real time data).

Now I'm wondering how to efficiently write structs in a list into a file.

```cs
List<struct_string> struct_list = new List<struct_string>(1000000);


FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

for (int num = 0; list_structs.Count > num; num++)
{
    streamWriter.Write( list_structs[num].string1 + ", " +
                        list_structs[num].string2 + ", " +
                        list_structs[num].string3 + ", " +
                        list_structs[num].string4 + ", " +
                        list_structs[num].string5 + "\r\n");
}

internal struct struct_string
{
    public string string1;
    public string string2;
    public string string3;
    public string string4;
    public string string5;

    public struct_string(string _string1, string _string2, string _string3, string _string4, string _string5)
    {
        string1 = _string1;
        string2 = _string2;
        string3 = _string3;
        string4 = _string4;
        string5 = _string5;
    }
}
```

This is what I could initially think of, but I think there should be built-in functions or better ways to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to save them to a file? Also, how do you build `list_structs`? It's not clear if its a `List<>` or an array or...?

Comment: Google for "serialization", what you are doing now is some kind of CSV file, consider json or xml instead (google for "c# json serialization").

Comment: Does it need to be a text file? That will invariably be slower than a binary file.

Comment: @Corentin Pane I'm new to C# and I'm trying to try one by one and I thought that CSV was the simplest and easiest.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for your comment. I'll look it up!

Comment: @Palle Due I'm a big fan of ```HDF5```, but ```HDF.PInvoke``` looks so difficult to use, so I was thinking that I could save data into a csv file and convert it into HDF5 using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read/write them to a binary file do this:

Define the struct:

```cs
[Serializable]
public struct X
{
    public int N {get; set;}
    public string S {get; set;}
}
```

Read and write it using a BinaryFormatter:

```cs
string filename = @"c:\temp\list.bin";
var list = new List<X>();
list.Add(new X { N=1, S="No. 1"});
list.Add(new X { N=2, S="No. 2"});
list.Add(new X { N=3, S="No. 3"});
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (System.IO.Stream ms = File.OpenWrite(filename))
{
    formatter.Serialize(ms, list);
}

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    object obj = formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    var newlist = (List<X>)obj;
    foreach (X x in newlist)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"N={x.N}, S={x.S}");
    }
}
```

The solution uses that the `List` class as well as the `X` struct is serializable.

Comment: Is it possible to serialize a new list and append it to the same binary file? How can I continuously save the list of structs?

Answer (score 1):

Try using serialization instead, you have libraries for that and with the new System.Text.Json in .NET Core you have really neat performance, another popular is Newtonsoft for standard .NET.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I looked it up and could find several libraries for that.